# Error al exportar un archivo csv en MySql

Tags: mysql

Buenas tardes, estoy tratando de exportar un archivo Excel a una tabla de MySql, mediante phpmyadmin.
Mi query es :

```
load data infile 'c:\\evasiondb.csv' into table `datos` fields terminated by ';'
```

me arroja el siguiente error.

Error
SQL query:

> load data infile 'c:\evasiondb.csv' into table `datos` fields
>   terminated by ';'
>
> MySQL said: Documentation
>
> ```
> #1045 - Access denied for user 'id2646211_db_admin'@'%' (using password: YES)
> ```

Saludos

Comment: Es un problema de autentificación. O bien el nombre de usuario constraseña no existen o son incorrectos, o bien no tiene permiso para ejecutar comandos del tipo `LOAD DATA`.

Comment: Ya me di cuenta de los errores y efectivamente era un error de permisos, por lo que tuve que exportar el archivo. En vez de cargarlo de esta manera.